# Sqlite-net datetime retrieval

Tags: .net, sqlite, datetime, sqlite-net

Hi I have a problem with retrieving datetime from SQLite database using sqlite-net library. Db column is of type DATE, example date in one of records is: **2013-08-02**

I have a model:

```
internal class FCost
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public DateTime AccountingDate { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I execute this line of code:

```
var result = dc.Table<FCost>().ToArray();
```

Every field except AccountingDate is filled correctly, all DateTime fields are filled with value: **{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}** (visual studio debbuger view). Why is date not parsed correctly? I tried switching Db column type to DATETIME and TEXT but got same results.

EDIT.
Object dc used above is of type SQLiteConnection from sqlite-net library.

Comment: I have entered values to AccountingDate column manually via SQLite Expert Professional (there is a built-in datepicker)

Answer (score 6):

There is a StoreDateTimeAsTicks property on the SQLiteConnection object that you should use. Set it to 'false'. Worked for me.

Comment: Should be accepted. Argument is sent on contructor and Date is filled

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **DATETIME**, USE Data type as  **Date**  to STORE DATE WITHOUT TIME.

Refer this.link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I indicated in my question that Db column (SQLite database side) is of type DATE. DateTime is .net type I use in my model. Also, I have tried storing date in database in a field of type DATETIME and TEXT, but as stated in my question, the results were the same.